# Populate multiple things based on 1 dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, html

I found the following example on the internet:

http://jsfiddle.net/b6ydm/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function dropdownTip(value){
    console.log(value);
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = value;
    }</script>

<select onChange="dropdownTip(this.value)" name="search_type" style="margin-right:10px; margin-top:2px;">
    <option selected="selected" value="fruit_search">fruits</option>    
    <option value="veggies_search">veggies</option>
    <option value="animals_search">animals</option>
    <option value="all_search">all</option>
</select>

<div id="result"></div>
```

I have adjusted it slightly for my own use and managed to put it into a table. The problem however is that I want to have multiple results based on 1 selection.

So if a person selects "Cat" in the dropdown list I want to populate A, B, C and D instead of just A.

It would be nice if someone could help me with this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you use jquery?  `$('#A, #B, #C, #D').html('' + value + '');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fiddle:**

**javscript:**

**http://jsfiddle.net/cT9j5/7/**

**jquery:**

**http://jsfiddle.net/cT9j5/8/**

```
<select onChange="dropdownTip(this.value)" name="search_type" style="margin-right:10px; margin-top:2px;">
    <option selected="selected" value="test1">fruits</option>    
    <option value="test2">veggies</option>
    <option value="test3">animals</option>
    <option value="test4">all</option>
</select>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Attributes</th>
        <th>values</th>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Strength</td>
        <td class="result"></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>dexterity</td>
        <td class="result"></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>intelligence</td>
        <td class="result"></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>wisdom</td>
        <td class="result"></td>
    </tr>    
</table>
```

**javascript:**

```
function dropdownTip(value){
    var myMap = {test1: ["10","20","30","10"],test2: ["20","22","31","11"],test3: ["11","24","31","44"],test4: ["12","21","34","14"]}
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("result");
    var len = elements.length;
    for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
        elements[i].innerHTML = eval("myMap."+value+"["+i+"]");
    }
```

}

Using jquery would be easier:

**jquery:**

```
function dropdownTip(value){
    var myMap = {test1: ["10","20","30","10"],test2: ["20","22","31","11"],test3: ["11","24","31","44"],test4: ["12","21","34","14"]}
    $(".result").each(function(i,e){
        $(this).html(eval("myMap."+value+"["+i+"]"));
    });
}
```

**Note:** `getElementsByClassName` is not supporte in lower versions of ie. in that case jquery would be better option.

Comment: I decided to use the regular Javascript solution that you gave which is working perfectly. The only problem that I have is that it displays 4 of the same result. Is it possible to change that? So instead of: fruit_search, fruit_search, fruit_search,fruit_search I want it to display test1, test2, test3 and test4. Thanks a lot by the way already!

Comment: you can change is by using `value+"something"`

Comment: That worked as well, nice! The only problem is that it shows up like test1test2 and I need to make it so that it's on top of each other in different columns. It's insane how much different options you have.

Comment: It's almost what I need, check this picture out: http://i57.tinypic.com/2jez6l2.png Hopefully you'll get what I mean.

Comment: so when you change dropdown you should get different values ?

Comment: Exactly, so for example when I select Alien as race it should display 2 strength, 4 intelligence, 3 wisdom and 10 dexterity but when I select mercian it should be displaying 20 strength, 2 intelligence, 40 wisdom and 2 dexterity. Every race will have 4 different values that should be displayed in the table.

Comment: Those are random values or fixed values ?

Comment: They are fixed values

Comment: I cannot upvote sadly enough but I did accept the answer. Thank you so much for everything! I really appreciate all of your help and I apologize for not being specific enough. Have a nice day sir, take care!

Comment: you are welcome. No need to address me as sir :D :D i am just 25

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jquery, and if A, B, C and D are all divs, like 'result', try this:

HTML

```
<select id="dropdownTip" name="search_type" style="margin-right:10px; margin-top:2px;">
<option selected="selected" value="fruit_search">fruits</option>    
<option value="veggies_search">veggies</option>
<option value="animals_search">animals</option>
<option value="all_search">all</option>
</select>

<div id="A"></div>
<div id="B"></div>
<div id="C"></div>
<div id="D"></div>
```

jquery

```
$('#dropdownTip').change(function() {
  var value = this.value;
   console.log(value);
    $('#A, #B, #C, #D').html('' + value + '');
  });
```

A, B, C and D will display the value of the selected option.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b6ydm/104/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying, I really appreciate it. I've replaced your function with the function I had and for some reason it doesn't display anything at the moment. Is there something else I need to change? I'm pretty new to JavaScript.

Comment: Please see full code above, and at the linked Fiddle.  Make sure you have jquery loaded.  If you need to load it from a CDN, you can add this to the page head or immediately before your opening script tag: `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use jquery to do this, will simplify things, but if you want to use javascript you still can do with it

html

```
<select id="selectMenu" style="margin-right:10px; margin-top:2px;">
    <option selected="selected" value="fruit_search">fruits</option>    
    <option value="veggies_search">veggies</option>
    <option value="animals_search">animals</option>
    <option value="all_search">all</option>
</select>

<div id="result1"></div>
<div id="result2"></div>
<div id="result3"></div>
```

JQuery

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#selectMenu").change(function(){
        $("#result1").append($(this).find(":selected").text());
        $("#result2").append($(this).find(":selected").text());
        $("#result3").append($(this).find(":selected").text());
    });
});
```

JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/agusgambina/b6ydm/106/

Hope helps